# why i don't hear beep using '\a' in xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

As far as I understan, using \a in printf argument suppose to give a beep sound of alert:

I'm doing `printf("\a");` but getting an upside down question mark...can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `\a` uses a hardware speaker that PCs use to beep during start up, etc. Maybe Macs don't have this?

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character:

> Modern terminal emulators often integrate the warnings to the desktop environment (e.g., the Mac OS X Terminal will play the system warning sound) and also often offer a silent visual bell feature that flashes the terminal window briefly.

Can you try running the exe from terminal and seeing if anything happens?

Comment: @user1959174 can you try running it from terminal? (see my edit)

Comment: "`\a` uses a hardware speaker" As the rest of your answer suggests, that's entirely up to the terminal (emulator). `\a` is in effect an instruction to the terminal to beep, just as `a` is in effect an instruction to the terminal to render a latin lower case a. Whoever writes the terminal decides how to do that. If you `printf("\a")` when stdout is going to a file, you don't get any sound, although you might then hear a beep each time you later display the file in a terminal.